# Definitions in Glossary?

Tags: thesis, glossary

While writing my thesis, I was putting down some definitions of terms as they are used in the scope of the work.

Does it make sense to move them to the glossary and write their definition as well? 
Looks like the Glossary is used mostly for acronyms in the thesis/diss I have seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense.

Doing so will add value to your thesis, if you do it well, and help the readers. Most people don't do this because they think of it too late or do not have the energy. Start doing it early and do it well, or don't do it at all.